# What determines the length of time it takes my heroku app to wake up?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I recently deployed my MERN app to heroku and I notice that to wake up it takes a very long time. It takes about 25 seconds whereas my friends similar app takes only 9 or 10 seconds to wake up. I just wanna know if there is any way I can improve this and what factors into how long this takes. Thanks.

Comment: Well, as an example, I used an ffmpeg buildpack that'd always fetch the latest ffmpeg binary on dyno startup, which could take a little bit. There's also what your app does as it's starting up that can vary.